# JavaScript array.some causing minification to stop working

Tags: javascript, minify

I am using the MVC bundling and minification in my project.

Everything works a treat, apart from one line, which is causing the minification to break.

I've tracked it down to the following javascript .some function.

```
        if (arr.some(x => x.Name == strName && x.Status == 0)) {
            // DO STUFF
        }
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is failing - this is the error I am getting

> (333,32-33): run-time error JS1195: Expected expression: 
>   (333,78-79): run-time
>   error JS1195: Expected expression: ) (333,80-81): run-time error
>   JS1004: Expected ';': {

Comment: Do you have the minified script?

Comment: It does not minify, that is the issue. It falls over trying to minify the lines above

Comment: maybe it has issue with minifying the `some` try something like `arr.filter(x=> x.Name == strName && x.Status == 0).length>0` and see if that minifies?